# Excel formula to find reference used by other cell

Tags: excel, reference, cell, max

Is there a way to find out the address of the cell being referenced in another cell in excel?

E.g. cell C1 contains formula =max(A:A) and returns a value of 10 which is actually referenced to cell A10. Can I use a formula in cell B that returns 'A10'?

And no, I don't want to use VBA at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your entries are in Cells A1:A7, you can do it this way ...

In Cell **B1**, the formula **=MAX(A1:A7)** and

in Cell **B2**, the cell location of the maximum number in the range (shown in B1) is given by the formula

**=CELL("address",INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(MAX(A1:A7),A1:A7,0)))**

OR

**=ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(A1:A7),$A$1:A7,0),1)**

Mark as answer if it helps.

Comment: Hi, I found this answer as well, but the problem is that the max function will fail if there's more than 1 maximum value and you want a certain criteria. E.g.

A 9000
B 9000
C 7000

I found a workaround, see below :)

Comment: `MAX` function do not fail. `MAX(9000, 9000, 7000)` is 9000. No doubt about it. @Kyle answer is correct to YOUR question.

Answer (score -2):

Managed to find the solution:

Similar to Kyle's formula, but instead we use match with multiple criteria to be more specific e.g.
=ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(A1:A7)&"A",$A$1:A7&$B$1:$B$7,0),1)

Comment: @Kyle answered your question. You changed question to give your own answer. Are you self promoting?

Comment: sorry i realised i didn't phrase my question accurately. Nevertheless, thanks for pointing that out!